# How to change functions according to valued in numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to make a surface plot of a function that looks like this:

```
def model(param,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4):
    est=param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2*x_3+x_2**2*x_4)
    return est
```

The point is that according to the value of x_2, x_3=1 for x_2>=0 and x_4=1 for x_2<0 (else:0).

When I tried to make a surface plot, I was confused how to make the mesh-grid as there are 2 more variables in addition to x_1 and x_2.

To compute the z axis, I tried to modify function as:

```
def function (param,x_1,x_2):
    if x_2>0:
      est=param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2)
    else:
      est=param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2**2)
    return est)
```

However, it says the truth value is ambiguous. I understood it as python sees it whether all values in x_2 >=0 or not.

I also tried to use np.sign() but it doesn't act in a way I want this case.

Would there be any ways to change the function according to the value of elenemt in the array and/or solve this without manually computing z axis using for loop?

Comment: `x_2` is an array not a scalar value. What does it mean `[-2, -1, 0, 1, 2] > 0`? Use `if all(x_2 > 0):`

Comment: Is possible add some sample data and expected ouput?

Comment: You may try something like x_3[x_2>0] =1 and proceed

Comment: Object have truth value in python, a vector is a collection of object thus it is ambiguous to have a single truth value for a vector (see all and any). What you can do is `(X > 2).all()` to ensure all components are above 2.

Comment: @Tommy. I downvoted your question by error. I edited your post to fix this mistake. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check all values greater than 0, use `all`:

```
def function (param,x_1,x_2):
    if all(x_2>0):
      est=param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2)
    else:
      est=param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2**2)
    return est
```

but if you want to apply the test on each value, use `np.where`:

```
def function (param,x_1,x_2):
    return np.where(x_2 > 0,
                    param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2),
                    param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2**2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
def function (param,x_1,x_2):
    return np.where(x_2>0, 
                    param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2), 
                    param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2**2))
```

How it working:

```
param = [10,8]
x_1 = np.array([1,2,3])
x_2 = np.array([0,4,10])
```

If `True`s in mask are used values from `param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2)` else from `param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2**2)`:

```
print (x_2>0)
[False  True  True]

print (param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2))
[ 18  58 114]

print (param[0]+param[1]*(x_1+x_2**2))
[ 18 154 834]

print (function(param,x_1,x_2))
[ 18  58 114]
```